# Regex: with repeated characters

Tags: regex, character

i'm trying to catch every two repeated characters in a word. I tried this:

```
(\w)\1+
```

but for some reason it only catches the first two pairs. For instance: the word "hellokitty", it catches the "ll" and ignores the other "tt" as tested in [regex101](http://regex101.com/)

Comment: Note that your expression does *not* 'catch every two repeated characters' – it catches *as many as possible* repeated characters. For example, in `w000t` it matches `000`. To match *any* two repeated characters, use `(\w)\1`. To match *only* two characters, you need `(\w)\1(?!\1)` (well actually `(\w)(?<!\1\1)\1(?!\1)` but as it appears you are not allowed: "Subpattern references are not allowed within a look behind assertion" – see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30678150/pcre-backreferences-not-allowed-in-lookbehinds for that).

Comment: Thank you very much i didn't notice that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to repeat a regex multiple times you have to use the `global` flag. On Regex101 that's just putting `g` in the box next to the regex.

How you have to use it in your code depends on the language you are using.

### Javascript

```js
/pattern/flags
new RegExp(pattern[, flags])
```

Example:

```js
regex = /(\w)\1+/g;
regex = new RegExp("(\w)\1+", "g");
```

### Python

```python
re.compile(pattern, flags=0)
```

**But** python doesn't have the `global` flag. To find all occurences, use:

```python
re.compile("(\w)\1+")
re.findall("Hellokitty")
```

This returns a tupple of matches.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use modifier `g` for global matching :

```
/(\w)\1/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/nW7vS1/1

Answer (score 0):

The `g` flag will make your regex **`global`** or repeating.

```
/(\w)\1+/g
```

## [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eZ1bZ1/2)

---

If you want it to prevent it from getting triple repeating things, you can remove the `+`:

```
/(\w)\1/g
```

## [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eZ1bZ1/1)