# lookbehind for start of string or a character

Tags: regex, python-2.7, regex-lookarounds

The command

```
re.compile(ur"(?<=,| |^)(?:next to|near|beside|opp).+?(?=,|$)", re.IGNORECASE)
```

throws a

`sre_constants.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern`

error in my program but [regex101](https://regex101.com/) shows it to be fine.

What I'm trying to do here is to match landmarks from addresses (each address is in a separate string) like:

- "Opp foobar, foocity" --> Must match "Opp foobar"
- "Fooplace, near barplace, barcity" --> Must match "near barplace"
- "Fooplace, Shoppers Stop, foocity"--> Must match nothing
- "Fooplace, opp barplace"--> Must match "opp barplace"

The lookbehind is to avoid matching words with `opp` in them (like in string 3).

Why is that error thrown? Is there an alternative to what I'm looking for?

Comment: Why: `<space>` and `,` are 1-width, `^` is 0-width, and Python can't handle the mismatch.

Comment: For the "why" see http://stackoverflow.com/a/30750398/2564301

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/lX0mL2/1 - "At start of string, or preceded by space or comma" `(?<=,| |^)` can be rewritten as "Not preceded by something that is not a space or a comma" `(?<![^ ,])` (always 1-width assertion, but since it's *negative* it will match at the beginning of the string as well).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
re.compile(ur"(?:^|(?<=[, ]))(?:next to|near|beside|opp).+?(?=,|$)", re.IGNORECASE)
```

You can club `3` conditions using `[]` and `|`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vA8cB3/2#python

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.findall` with the below regex, since `re.findall` must return the contents insdie the capturing group if there is any capturing group presents.

```
re.compile(ur"(?m)(?:[, ]|^)((?:next to|near|beside|opp).+?)(?:,|$)", re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: This did work for me but I dont understand what the `(?m)` does. Can you give a short explanation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918806/difference-between-regular-expression-modifiers-m-and-s